# Find regex in file with boost

Tags: c++, regex, file, boost

I'd like to do something like this:

```
boost::regex re("tryme");
ifstream iss;
iss.open("file.txt");
istream_iterator<string> eos;     
istream_iterator<string> iit (iss);

find(iit,eos,bind2nd(boost::regex_match),re));
```

The errors are following:

> Could not find a match for 'bind2nd<_Fn2,_Ty>(bool (*)       (BidiIterator,BidiIterator,match_results &,const basic_regex &,unsigned long))'
>
> Could not find a match for 'find(istream_iterator,int>,istream_iterator,int>,undefined,regex)'

Could you please help me to do it correctly? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that `std::find()` tries to match values, i.e., you need to replace `std::find()` by `std::find_if()`. That's simple to do.

The next problem is that `boost::regex_match` isn't one function but a family of functions. `std::bind2nd()` has no idea which member of this family you want to match against. Also, the function overload you apparently want to use takes three, not two, arguments: the last argument of type `boost::match_flag_type` is defaulted. I got it to work with `std::bind()` using this:

```
std::bind(static_cast<bool (*)(std::string const&,
                               boost::regex const&,
                               boost::match_flag_type)>(&boost::regex_match),
         std::placeholders::_1, re);
```

If you really want to use `std::bind2nd()` it is probably easiest to create a simple forwarding function:

```
bool my_regex_match(std::string s, boost::regex const& r) {
    return boost::regex_match(s, r);
}

void f() {
    boost::regex re("tryme");
    std::ifstream iss(file.txt);
    std::find_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
             std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
             std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(&my_regex_match), re));
}
```

The `std::bind2nd()` template cannot really work with raw function pointers. This is why `std::ptr_fun()` needs to be used. In general, when any of the standard functions called `*_fun()` need to be used, the fun actually stops: these functions cannot cope with functions taking arguments by reference. Thus, `my_regex_match()` takes its `std::string` argument by value: `std::bind2nd()` would try to create a function object taking a reference to reference as argument otherwise. This is another reason why you might want to use `std::bind()` or `boost::bind()`.